# Biblioteca "Windows.h" o que me permite realizar?

Tags: c, windows

*Estou começando na linguagem C e gostaria de saber o que a biblioteca "Windows.h" corresponde?! ela é responsável pelo que?! que tipo de funções ela me permite?!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrescentando a resposta do DBX8, como o `windows.h` é específico do Windows, você deve tomar cuidados especiais quando estiver desenvolvendo códigos que pretenda depois reutilizar em outros sistemas.

Por exemplo, quando você faz o include:

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

Você limita o seu código para o Windows.
Mas, com o seguinte código, você trata essa questão:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 

// O #ifdef acima garante que o sistema é Windows pois
// o compilador possui _WIN32 definido para os sistemas Windows,
// mas não em outros sistemas.
#include <Windows.h>

#else // ou #elif TESTE_DO_SISTEMA

// #includes do outro sistemas alvo.
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#endif
```

E, logicamente, a implementação do código será diferente para cada sistema.
Mesmo que seu objetivo não seja suportar outros sistemas, é bom adicionar pelo menos o seguinte:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 

#include <Windows.h>
// Outros includes 

#else

// Dá mensagem de erro informando que o sistemas não é suportado.
#error "Sistema nao suportado."

#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

`windows.h` contém declarações para todas as funções da [API do Windows](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API), todos os macros comuns utilizados pelos programadores do Windows, e todos os tipos de dados utilizados pelas várias funções e subsistemas.

Possibilita você a fazer coisas como:

- Criar janelas e botões.
- Enumerar arquivos de um diretório.
- Consultar informações sobre o sistema(eg processos, serviços, janelas).
- Coisas do gênero.

Veja esse [`índice da API do Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(*ᵉᶰ*), isso deverá ser útil ler.

<sub>[`Wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h)</sub>

Exemplo simples, uma janela:

```
#include <windows.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "ClassedaJanela";

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "Simple Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: DBX8 todos os exemplos que vi utilizando essa biblioteca deram erro, eu estou atrás de um exemplo, linhas de código utilizando essa biblioteca, vi exemplos para mexer com funções do windows tipo interfaces, bonequinhos se mexendo enfim.. mas todos que eu vi deram erro.

Comment: "todos os exemplos que vi utilizando essa biblioteca deram erro" - recomendo usar tutoriais, e começar por algo menos avançado do que usar a API do Windows.